# Artifactory GUI accessible locally but not from another computer

Tags: tomcat, artifactory

I installed Artifactory 6.6 on a server running Ubuntu 18.04. I didn't change the configuration whatsoever and just started the service. I can access the GUI with 'localhost:8081' as well as '[MyIP]:8081' from the server itself but it won't work from another computer (connection timeout).

I allowed incoming traffic on port 8081 (sudo ufw status returns: 8081 ALLOW Anywhere) and I can ping the server from the other computer (so it means that it is not a networking issue).
In addition tomcat/conf/server.xml Connector does not contain any specific IP address:

```
Connector port="8081" sendReasonPhrase="true" relaxedPathChars='[]' relaxedQueryChars='[]'/>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

please first check if the artifactory listens on local host or all IPs:

```
netstat -tulnp | grep 8081
```

if you get that 8081 listens on 0.0.0.0 then the problem is not in the server.

try accessing from another server:

```
telnet <ARTIFACTORY_IP> 8081
```

if this fails it means it is a firewall issues of some sort.